# Функция перестановки двух элементов списка

Tags: c++, списки

Нужно было создать функцию  перестановки двух элементов динамического списка. Я её сделал но функция не работала. Тогда мне подсказали сделать проверку и я не совсем понимаю  зачем она нужна( строки с проверкой я обозначил \ в коде )

```
void SwapLst(List* lst, int id1, int id2)
   {
         int id;

         Itm *temp1 = NULL, *temp2 = NULL;
         Itm *prev1, *prev2, *next1, *next2;

         lst->cur = lst->bg;

         while(lst->cur != NULL){
            if(lst->cur->id == id1){
                temp1 = lst->cur;
            }
            if(lst->cur->id == id2){
                temp2 = lst->cur;
            }
            lst->cur = lst->cur->next;
         }

         if(temp1 == NULL || temp2 == NULL) return;

         prev1 = temp1->prev;
         prev2 = temp2->prev;
         next1 = temp1->next;
         next2 = temp2->next;

         \\ if(prev1 != NULL){
             prev1->next = temp2;
         }
         \\ if(prev2 != NULL){
             prev2->next = temp1;
         }
         \\ if(next1 != NULL){
             next1->prev = temp2;
         }
         \\ if(next2 != NULL){
             next2->prev = temp1;
         } 

         temp1->next = next2;
         temp1->prev = prev2;
         temp2->next = next1;
         temp2->prev = prev1;

         if(prev1 == NULL){
            lst->bg = temp2;
         }

         if(prev2 == NULL){
            lst->bg = temp1;
         }

         if(next1 == NULL){
            lst->end = temp2;
         }

         if(next2 == NULL){
            lst->end = temp1;


 }
```

}

Comment: Реализация только для кольцевого списка. Иначе, как сказано ниже prev и next могут быть nullptr. Ещё одна ошибка, которая ошибка при любой реализации: подумайте что будет, если элементы идут подряд. допустим temp1 перед temp2. На что будет указывать next1 и prev2? Верно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как зачем - если, например, `temp1` оказался первым элементом, то `prev` для него не существует, и как тогда обращаться к `NULL->next`?

```
 prev1 = temp1->prev;

 \\ if(prev1 != NULL){
         prev1->next = temp2;
```

Comment: Это зависит от того, как List реализован. Если это кольцевой список, то вполне существует.